# Adding PTPv2 layer to scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I want to add a PTPv2 Layer to scapy (v2.3.3) in python (v2.7). I added the ptpv2 class with the PTP entries to the file /scapy/layers/inet.py (because PTP is at layer 4). I also bound the ptpv2 layer to the upper layer, in my case Ethernet.

```
bind_layers(Ethernet,ptpv2)
```

By typing the scapy command "ls()" the created ptpv2 layer is listed, ok, success. But by accessing the layer through the python commands

```
for packet in PcapReader('/media/sf_SharedFolder/test.pcap'):
  if packet[ptpv2].sequenceId == anything:
    # do sth
```

the following error occurs:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 817, in __getitem__
  raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [ptpv2] not found
```

The Wireshark file has the layers Frame -> Ethernet -> PTP, so my binding command has to be right.

Don't know where the error is.

Pls, help me!

Thx

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dissector is probably failing, but Scapy hides that and decodes the layer as `Raw()`.

You can:

- check that by checking that `packet.payload` is a `Raw` instance.
- try to find what crashes in your dissector by setting `conf.debug_dissector = True`.

Comment: I added "conf.debug_dissector = True". The next error occurs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 75, in getfield
    return  s[self.sz:], self.m2i(pkt, struct.unpack(self.fmt, s[:self.sz])[0])
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2

Comment: Nope, sry, only more error informations through "conf.debug_dissector=True". Error still exists. I didn't edit my question to another topic, I edited my question to more information.

Comment: Ok, then I ask a new question.